# Approval link in email body

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-mvc, html-email

Need help in implementing email based approval system. Ex: Manager gets an auto triggered mail for his/her approval with a approval link in email body, when the manager clicks on the the link, it should validate the manager and then approve it. I tried searching on the internet but didn't find relevant resource.

Request you to Please help me with your ideas, suggestions or how I should proceed, or any plugin or jar is available??? It would be very helpful to me... Thanking you...

EDIT: Thanking you for replying. We have a java web app build using spring framework (MVC) where in employees can apply leaves which has to be approved by his/her manager. If an employee applies leave then a mail is triggered for approval to his/her manager with the leave details. After looking the mail, the manager logs-in to the application to approve or reject the leaves. So request you to Please help me in how to give a direct link in the mail to approve or reject the leaves.

Comment: Not really a good SO-type question, but having done something similar I used Velocity as an email template, used Spring MVC and Spring Security for the web app.  Generate a URL with UUID key as part of the end, use path variables to pick up the generated ID and display the proper approval page.  It's not really rocket science or anything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... But as I am new to this, I don't have idea how to do it... I am facing problem in validating an approver... Only the valid approver should able to approve it... Other =wise it should it should show proper error message...

Answer (score 3):

[For one of our applications](https://github.com/techdev-solutions/trackr-backend) we had the same requirements - employees can submit vacation requests and supervisors will be notified via mail. We have written an article about the exact way we did it - available [here](https://techdev.io/de/developer-blog/mail-approvals-with-spring-integration).

So in a nutshell, we are using Spring Integration and GMail. Each new vacation request yields an email send to all supervisors. Supervisors can reply with either *approve* or *reject*. We only accept email addresses from our domain, but since these can be faked we introduced a shared secret - a UUID added to the mail's subject which then relates to the id of the vacation request.

Once an email comes in we run the business logic to figure out whether a request shall be approved or rejected.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, I used [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) to template my email message.  You don't have to use it, but it made my job easier.  You should be able to read up on it.

Java itself has the ability to [send emails](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/javamail/javamail.html) in it's Java EE framework using JavaMail, or you can use [Spring's wrappers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mail.html).  You will need access to a mail server of some sorts, and would highly recommend that you setup an email box specifically for this process.  I actually used my gmail account during testing, but I wouldn't recommend that for a long-term solution.  I assume your company would have an email server setup somewhere you can use.

The process flow would be:

1. Employee fills out request
2. System generates an email to employee's manager(s) with a link to approve
3. Manager clicks on link, taken to approval page
4. Manager approves/denies request

The next question is how to build the URL.  I would suggest using something like a UUID or something like that, or the request ID if that makes it easier.  You can generate a UUID from any seed String or set of bytes.  I like UUID because it obviscates the data being sent.

Anyway, the URL will basically point to a Spring form that will allow the user to approve that request.  So, thinking about what you would need, I would expect some DB record that relates the information in the incoming request to the time off request that was filled out.  Read in the record, load the page and display it.  Simple enough.

The next issue is locking it down so only the authorized people can approve.  Again, making a huge assumption here, but I am guessing you are using Spring Security?  If you are, you should be able to add a condition to the Controller's handler for this approval form that requires the user to be authenticated ([read here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)) and add a java.security.Principal to the handler methods arguments ([read 15.3.2.3 here for what you can pass into a Controller's handler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)).  With the Principal object in-hand, you should be able to compare that to a list of approvers associated with the request record in the DB.  I would then have the system generate approval/denial emails that code to all concerned parties.

Let me reiterate that this is NOT the only solution, only one possible solution.  This is why I feel this is not a good question for StackOverflow, as it asks a very broad question that doesn't really have a single *right* answer.